# How to use Django without database

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an app with a React frontend. The purpose of the backend is to call a public API, process the data retrieved from the public API, and then with a REST API transfer the post-processed data to the view (React frontend). I would like to use python in the backend, so I started with using Django. However, it seems Django is very much focused on Models and Databases. I do not need a database for this app. Is Django the right tool to use for this?

Comment: if the database is not your concern is the app not taking anything from the backend or is the backend not taking anything from the front end?

Comment: @nava The frontend requests from the backend. The backend calls a public API, processes the data, and then sends something to frontend to display. Nothing is stored in a database.

Comment: yes you can do that just use django views with serializer it is easy to do or you may post public API I can do rest part for you

Comment: @nava Ok cool thanks. And would I still have Models in order to Model the data I'm sending into the frontend?

Comment: no, you won't need any model just return API JSON response as Response from your API but if you want to save certain info from API you will need model hope I clarified you.

Comment: @nava Yep that all makes sense. I will try to figure it out now, thanks!

Comment: you can use Flask or FastAPI; django is a battery included framework if your requirements is only for API call django could be a heavy for you.

Comment: @ShishirSubedi awesome, been trying and this feels very heavyweight for my needs. Thanks